# Does this program violate the ODR?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Consider this program:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> constexpr bool g() { return true; }
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t< g<T>()> f() {}
template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<!g<T>()> f() {}

int main() { f<int>(); }
```

([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/r93e9zrsn))

It is acceptable to various versions of GCC and Clang, but it is not acceptable to MSVC, which fails to compile with the error message

```
1>D:\x.cpp(5,49): error C2995: 'enable_if<0,void>::type f(void)': function template has already been defined
1>D:\x.cpp(4): message : see declaration of 'f'
1>D:\x.cpp(4,49): error C3861: 'f': identifier not found
```

The first error message suggests an ODR violation to me - but if this program is ill-formed NDR, I need help understanding why that is so.  I've checked [[temp.over.link]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link) in the standard draft, but I'm not confident that I'm interpreting it correctly.  To my understanding the program is okay because these function templates have differing signatures.

In the unlikely case this program is correct, why does MSVC reject it?

Comment: Why "unlikely"?

Comment: @JeffGarrett "Unlikely" because I'm ignorant about this corner of the spec, and violations of the one definition rule don't require a compiler to emit diagnostic messages (such programs are ill-formed, No Diagnostic Required).  So either there's a compiler bug, or MSVC is the only compiler to complain about my incorrect code.  :)

Comment: Then your last statement doesn't convey that; you're using "unlikely" incorrectly. The way you've phrased it, it seems like you think it's *probable* that the code is incorrect. Just  say "*In case this program is incorrect, ...*".

Comment: The problem with the "function template signatures" is that the signature belongs to the **instantiation** of the template. And both templates would have the same return type, if instantiated. However, template arguments **also** belong to the signature, which is why the code is correct. For any `T`, exactly one of the two templates can be instantiated. Without an instantiation, there's no signature.

Comment: @MSalters, that statement is confusing, because a function template does have a signature, and the return types being the same for two template instantiations doesn't tell you the function templates have the same signature because the signature (may) include the expression that led to that type.

Answer (score 4):

MSVC has a bug here.

For most functions, equivalence of arguments is sufficient to indicate an error.  For templates, the return type expression is also involved.

MSVC seems to be ignoring the return type expression, and generating an error as if it could ignore it.

The `g<T>()`/`!g<T>()` part could be split into `sizeof(T)==1` and `sizeof(T)!=1` to remove one other confounding feature (the fact that one of those two cannot in practice be instantiated).

Try this:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<g<T>(),bool> =true> void f() {}
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!g<T>(),bool> =true> void f() {}
```

it will work in all 3 compilers.

Comment: I think this answer should be improved. "For most functions, equivalence of arguments is sufficient to indicate an error. ". This is ambiguous. When should the error be detected? When declared, or when overload resolution fails? This becomes relevant once you consider templates.